# Android: How to find out why app launch failed?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, logcat

I am attempting to launch a simple test app on the Android emulator (developing in Eclipse 3.6 on Windows).

Here is the logcat result:

```
[2011-05-11 11:35:49 - androidtest] Android Launch!
[2011-05-11 11:35:49 - androidtest] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-11 11:35:49 - androidtest] Performing androidtest.AndroidTestActivity activity launch
[2011-05-11 11:35:49 - androidtest] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'HTC_Incredible' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-11 11:35:49 - androidtest] Uploading androidtest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-11 11:35:49 - androidtest] Installing androidtest.apk...
[2011-05-11 11:38:40 - androidtest] Failed to install androidtest.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-05-11 11:38:40 - androidtest] (null)
[2011-05-11 11:38:41 - androidtest] Launch canceled!
```

How can I determine why this launch failed?

Comment: Is your minSDKVersion greater than the API level of Emulator?

Comment: No, already checked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the Eclipse Console output and not the LogCat. The LogCat output might provide a clue to what goes wrong.

I know from experience that the adb doesn't always work properly when it has been running for a while, so killing the adb.exe process and restarting it might also help.

Answer (score 2):

The single answer to this problem:

**This is a common problem that the emulator sometimes get disconnected from eclipse and uploading and installing of apk file can't be done, to resolve this just close the emulator and run again.**

I've faced the same many times myself:)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is appear first time when you try to run your first application. It may be because of disconnection between the virtual device and .apk file. try to close the emulator and restart it or delete the emulator and create new emulator.